# What is Design Pattern where we can pass the string name to a method and that method chooses which further method to call

Tags: android, design-patterns

I recently got following example where we are passing the action name to the method as string and then the method decides the function that needs to be called.

is this a good way of solving problem or is there some better way as well

```
public static final String ACTION_CHARGING_REMINDER = "charging-reminder";
public static void executeTask(Context context, String action) {
    if (ACTION_INCREMENT_WATER_COUNT.equals(action)) {
        incrementWaterCount(context);
    } else if (ACTION_DISMISS_NOTIFICATION.equals(action)) {
        NotificationUtils.clearAllNotifications(context);
    } else if(ACTION_CHARGING_REMINDER.equals(action)){
        issueChargeReminder(context);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this. This can be extended as much as you want, and obviously just an example:

```
static abstract class ActionHandler {

    private String action;

    public ActionHandler(String action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

    public boolean canHandleAction(String input) {
        return this.action.equals(input);
    }

    public abstract void handleAction();
}

static class OneActionHandler extends ActionHandler {

    public OneActionHandler(String action) {
        super(action);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleAction() {
        //...
    }
}

static class TwoActionHandler extends ActionHandler {

    public TwoActionHandler(String action) {
        super(action);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleAction() {
        //...
    }
}

static class Test {

    private ActionHandler[] handlers;

    public Test() {
        handlers = new ActionHandler[]{new OneActionHandler("action1"), new TwoActionHandler("action2")};
    }

    public void handleAction(String action) {
        for(ActionHandler i : handlers) {
            if(i.canHandleAction(action)) {
                i.handleAction();
                break;
            }
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: In this particular case. I'd rather use if/else instead of introducing that many classes

Comment: Thats like three classes, which then you can indepenendently test and change the implementation, add new cases etc. without much code changes

Comment: You know,  you'd consider amount of information before applying any design pattern. This `chain of responsibility-like` design pattern introduces much complexity

Comment: You obviously never worked on big applications if you think this is "too much complexity". Being lazy early on just makes your life even harder later. OP does not specify how much he does in this application, but its obvious he deals with things like notifications, reminders which suggest me it might be a complex app. Anyway, this is a pointless talk because I did not ask you to comment on how "complex" it is nor anyone else: OP can decide if he wants to use it or not. Feel free to add another answer instead of suggesting this is "too complex" for an app you dont even know...

Comment: My apologize.  The OP did ask for a `design pattern` so `chain of responsibilities` is best suitable for this case. But I suggest you to make it become a real chain. Create a method to register for new handler and have the item in chain call the next one registered instead of for-each loop

Comment: No worries. It's up to OP. Though I have used Spring Framework when even smaller apps can reach a level of complexity otherwise unwanted. Once you start extending it later it really helps that every class has a separate responsibility for example.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like the react/redux, [action/reduction](https://redux.js.org/basics/actions) pattern.

> Reducers specify how the application's state changes in response to
>   actions sent to the store. Remember that actions only describe what
>   happened, but don't describe how the application's state changes.